# How to arrange subfigure IDs in small grid outside figure?

Tags: subfloats

Essentially, I'm wondering how to have the subfigure IDs (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) in a small grid as it's done here.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: This is just a simple tabular with color. (`colortbl`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, using the `subcaption` package for the image arrangement and numbering as well as a colored tabular for the small grid:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf, figurename=FIGURE}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\phantomsubcaption\label{subfig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\phantomsubcaption\label{subfig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\phantomsubcaption\label{subfig:c}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip

    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\phantomsubcaption\label{subfig:d}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\phantomsubcaption\label{subfig:e}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\phantomsubcaption\label{subfig:f}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip

    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\phantomsubcaption\label{subfig:g}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\phantomsubcaption\label{subfig:h}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\phantomsubcaption\label{subfig:i}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
    \rowcolors{1}{lightgray}{lightgray}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
       \subref{subfig:a} & \subref{subfig:b} & \subref{subfig:c} \\
       \hline
       \subref{subfig:d} & \subref{subfig:e} & \subref{subfig:f} \\
       \hline
       \subref{subfig:g} & \subref{subfig:h} & \subref{subfig:i} \\
    \end{tabular}
    \captionsetup{justification=raggedright}
    \caption{(\subref{subfig:a}) text text text.  (\subref{subfig:b}) text text text. (\subref{subfig:c}) through (\subref{subfig:i}), text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text } \label{figure}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```